# Get last row in table of time series?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am already able to get the last row of time-series table as:

```
SELECT * from myapp.locations WHERE organization_id=1 and user_id=15 and date='2017-2-22'  ORDER BY unix_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

That works fine, however, I am wondering about performance and overhead of executing `ORDER BY` as rows are already sorted, I just use it to get the last row, is it an overhead in my case?

If I don't use `ORDER BY`, I will always get the first row in the table, so, I though I might be able to use `INSERT` in another way, ex: insert always in the beginning instead of end of table?

Any advice? shall I use `ORDER BY` without worries about performance?

Comment: show us your table schema

Comment: here: https://gist.github.com/hopewise/04f0310629151408f9f019e8d4046546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just define your clustering key order to DESC**

Like the below schema :

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    organization_id int,
    user_id int,
    date text,
    unix_time bigint,
    lat double,
    long double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((organization_id, user_id, date), unix_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (unix_time DESC);
```

So by default your data will sorted by unix_time desc, you don't need to specify in query
Now you can just use the below query to get the last row :

```
SELECT * from myapp.locations WHERE organization_id = 1 and user_id = 15 and date = '2017-2-22' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query pattern for that table is always `ORDER BY unix_time DESC` then you are in a *reverse order time-series* scenario, and I can say that your model is *inaccurate* (not wrong).

There's no reason not to sort the records in reverse order by adding a `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY unix_time DESC` in the table definition, and in my opinion the `ORDER BY unix_time DESC` will perform at most on par with something explicitly meant for these use cases (well, I think it will perform worse).

Comment: `well, I think it will perform worse` do you mean that `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY unix_time DESC` will have bad impact on performance?

Comment: @simo: no, I meant that a query with `ORDER BY unix_time DESC` will perform worse than a table with `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY unix_time DESC`. By design.